# Posterior prediction of future parameters, not future outcomes

Tags: bayesian, prediction

Suppose I have a model y_i ~ N(a + bX, sigma). If I wanted to generate a forecast and compare it to future data, I'd use y_new ~ N(a + bX_new, sigma). My question is: what if I want to compare a future prediction of just the parameter b? What should be the comparison in the future?

For example, if we have a posterior prediction of b from a Bayesian model, then what method should we use to compare it to a future b? Should we just do an OLS regression of b and determine the success of our prediction relative to that?

This is all new to me.

Comment: In bayesian case you can also build credible intervals for parameter `b` and check if the classic ols fit is in those intervals!

Comment: In your model the parameter b is a constant. The first you need to do is a model where b actually is b_y, changing with time. Please tell us the real-world context, otherwise this is to broad!